# Twig - render block from included or parent template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

is there any way to render block from included or parent template?

I have 3 templates

main.html.twig:

```
{% include 'navbar.html.twig' %}

<div id="main_content">
    {% block application_content %}
    {% endblock application_content %}
</div>

{% block application_footer %}
    footer
{% endblock application_footer %}
```

navbar.html.twig:

```
<p>bla bla</p>
{% block navbar_profile_photo %}
    <img src="{{ image }}">
{% endblock navbar_profile_photo %}
```

content.html.twig:

```
{% extends "main.html.twig" %}

{% block application_content %}
   lorem ipsum

   {% block foo %}
       dolor sit amet
   {% endblock foo %}

{% endblock application_content %}
```

**I want to be able call something like this**

> $twig->loadTemplate('content.html.twig')->renderBlock('navbar_profile_photo', array('image' => 'bar.jpg'))

But I can get only blocks from 'content.html.twig'

> $twig->loadTemplate('content.html.twig')->getBlockNames();

returns

> ['application_content', 'foo']

I could add to content.html.twig

> {% use 'navbar.html.twig' %}

but in my case I had to do it in many templates with many different use statements

Is there some way to get the final template with all includes and extends and blocks?

Answer (score 0):

In content.html.twig file you must add:

```
{% extends "EverlutionApplicationBundle::main.html.twig" %}
{% block navbar_profile_photo %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock navbar_profile_photo %}
.....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not correct. [Parent](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) function is for different purpose. Yes I can see now block `navbar_profile_photo`, but it's brand new block, not the one from `navbar.html.twig`